# Select/Remove vertices joining only two edges

Tags: vertices

I'm trying to find a way to select (and remove) vertices on the edge of a subdivided plane without having to go round and highlight each one separately.
I want to keep vertices terminating three or more edges, but remove those linking only two (leaving a contiguous edge, naturally) – any ideas? I'm thinking either there's an embarrassingly easy solution or it's not possible and I'm the only person not to know it.[image: Illustration showing vertices terminating only two edges]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *Select Similar*  menu in vertex selection mode to select vertices which share only 2 edges (in 2.79 it is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). Switch to vertex selection mode, select one vertex falling into mentioned category and with it selected run *Select Similar* > *Amount of connecting edges*.

> **Amount of Connecting Edges**
>   Selects all vertices that have the same number of edges connected to them.

[Select Similar in manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-similar)

Vertices which share only 2 edges will be selected and you can dissolve them with <kbd>X</kbd> * > Dissolve Vertices*.

Comment: Just what I was looking for – thanks. Selecting the item *beforehand*; what an idea. Moral: running Blender when tired can seriously damage your sanity.